# How to Change Read-Only Status of Files in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a  Java project and I want to modify it in intellij but I can't do it because of this **" read-only file "** or **"file is not writable"** , so how I can modify and execute it?

[image: this is the problem]

Comment: I also googled it; google also links to SO...

Comment: @ayip I just did, and google pulled this up as the first search results to lead me here.

Comment: Just a cent: For one reason or another, when opening a project something bad happened inside of IntelliJ (with an error pop-up) and it marked the project as read-only. After removing the .idea-folder and reopening the project all was fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72835869/how-to-make-file-writable-on-intellij#answer-72836019

Answer (score 39):

To toggle read-only attribute of a file, open file in the editor, or select it in the Project tool window. Do one of the following:

- On the main menu, choose `File | File Properties | Make File Read-Only`, or `Make File Writable`.

[image]

- Click the lock icon in the Status bar in the bottom right corner.

[image]

Comment: A screenshot for this answer would be great

Comment: I added a screenshot and updated the text for current release (2002.2.3)

Answer (score 29):

If IntelliJ IDEA is unable to change the file permissions using **File | File Properties | Make File Writable**, then perhaps another user is owning that file, e.g. root (use this command to verify: `ls -hal /path/to/File.java`)

If someone else owns it, for whatever reason, you can change the permissions yourself using the [chown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) command in the terminal:

`sudo chown yourusername /path/to/File.java`,

where `yourusername` is the same user that you used to launch Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Worked for me by `chmod 0777 /path-to-file`. Thanks

Comment: How to do this for Windows?

Answer (score 29):

For Mac, this definitely works:

`sudo chmod -R 777 /YourDirectory`

Comment: This reminds me of https://xkcd.com/1217/. OP has an issue with a single file, so while changing all rights of all files under the root directory work, it’s almost always a bad solution. It’s like removing all walls of your house just because you lost the key of one door.

Answer (score 14):

I was just having this issue and I finally figured out where I was going wrong.

Over an hour of suggestions from Google didn't help. It turns out I was on files selected in the -out > production > MyPath folder instead of the -src folder in my project sidebar. Selecting the -scr > MyClass file allows me to do what I want to do.

Comment: Thank you for this! Sometimes it's the simplest of things

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Mac. Follow bellow steps:

1. Open that file by Finder
2. Right click and select `Get Info`
3. In that File Info window, select `Sharing and Permissions`, change `Privilege` as you expected. Before changing, you would remember unlocking your change permission by click on a `Locker Icon` at bottom right.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case of working with SAP Hybris in IntelliJ, the OOTB module files are read-only (file is not writable) when you import the project with Hybris plugins.

- While you are importing the project (re-import the project If already
  imported) , you will be prompted for Import Settings.
- Uncheck the **Import OOTB modules in read-only mode**.
- After importing , you should be able to edit the OOTB files.

[image: Import Settings]

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this situation as well. Here is the solution that worked for me.

When you open a file from Intellij do not choose the main folder which contains the src file, but choose the src file itself and open it. This way it let me write my code again.

Answer (score 0):

On your top-left corner in the drop-down where you have Tests,Production,Problems switch/choose from Project or any other directory you've choosen  to Packages, you'll have your packages editable, files in the Project folder are not editable although they end with `.class` extension.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when the other user has created those files.
1. Right click on the file or folder to be deleted.
2. Choose reveal in folder option.
3. Delete the file and enter the password.
4. Files will be deleted.