# How to toggle Read-Only Status recursively for all files in a given folder

Tags: windows, file, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, readonly

Related to [how to toggle read-only for a single file in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44265670/7123519) but different in that I want to know how to do it recursively for all files in a given folder at once.

Since I haven't been able to find a solution using IntelliJ so far, I assume it's not possible. For that reason, my question is more specifically: how to toggle read-only status of all files in a folder using the terminal of IntelliJ on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

> how to toggle read-only status of all files in a folder using the terminal of IntelliJ on Windows 10.

On a Windows (FAT/NTFS at very least) it's just a matter of setting up (or removing) a Read Only attribute. Adjust the folder path as needed.

- Old good **cmd.exe** (`-R` to remove, `+R` to set):

  ```
  attrib -R C:\Temp\*.*
  ```
- **PowerShell** command will be something like this:

  ```powershell
  # This affects only files in THAT folder, no folders or files in subfolders
  Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp" -File | foreach {$_.IsReadOnly = $false}

  # This one will affect ALL files in that folder and all subfolders
  Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp" -File -Recurse | foreach {$_.IsReadOnly = $false}
  ```

Notes:

- Use `$false` to remove that attribute and `$true` to set it.
- Can replace `Get-ChildItem -Path` by just `dir` (will work in such command).

Do not forget to use `File | Reload All from Disk` after such external manipulation.

**P.S.** Such command can be implemented as an [External Tools entry](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-third-party-tools.html) so it will be available in the Project View context menu... or even assign some custom shortcut (but be careful with that as context (current folder) is important here).

---

> Since I haven't been able to find a solution using IntelliJ so far, I assume it's not possible.

Why? You can do the same using IDE functionality. Just select multiple files and use that command: `File | File Properties | Make File Read-Only` (will become `Make File Writable` if they are already in that mode; will show `Toggle Read-Only Attribute` if they are mixed).

Here I have selected 2 files (`3.php` and `4.php`) and used floating Main Menu (otherwise it covers the files) to show the command:

[image]

Comment: To address your last point, I already knew that. However, it doesn't work when the given folder contains a lot of complex nested subdirs, then you can't just shift select all files without also including the subdirs.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen It was not clear that you want to affect all files: in that folder and all subfolders. Updated my PowerShell example to provide both options.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen Have you tried the updates? The PowerShell command that does it for ALL files recursively.

Comment: Actually "recursively for all files in a given folder" in the Unix/Linux world means subdirs should be affected because that's how they use the word recursion.

Comment: @H2ONaCl Original question did not had the "recursively" word in the title or question body -- it was added later (check the edit history and timings)