# How to make file writable on IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jetbrains-ide

I am using **IntelliJ to build JavaFX applications**. I am trying to make changes to my Java controller class `HelloController.java` but unable to because the **File is read-only**. However, the other files such as the main java class `HelloApplication.java` and the FXML file are all writable.

I went to *"File | File Properties"* to make it writable again but the option does not even show. It still shows **"Make File read only"** when it is already a **read only** file.

[image: File is read-only prompt]

[image: Make file writable option does not appear]

Comment: You're trying to edit the class file in your `target` directory, instead of the Java file in your `src/main/java` directory.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the title bar for the tab, it says `HelloController.class` *not* `HelloController.java`.

A class file is binary, not text.  The class file is compiled output and, with your setup, is placed under the `target` directory.  It is not a source file.  You can see the message that Idea decompiled the class (turned the binary code to text), but you cannot edit decompiled text.  This is why it is read only.

Instead you should be editing the source file which is named `HelloController.java` under the `src/main/java/com/example/calapp` directory.